# Uso de una Interface y una List<T>

Tags: c#, unity3d

Si tengo una Interface que después la implemento en una clase, esta cuando la implemente en una List, T puede ser el nombre de la interface?

Interface:

```
interface IItem
{
    int id { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
}
```

Clase serializada:

```
[System.Seriazable]
public class Martillo : IItem
{
    public int damage { get; set; }

    // Implement interface  IItem
    int id { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
}
```

Metodo diccionario:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<T> addDictionary<T>( T _item, string _index){

     Dictionary<string, List<T> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<T>();    
     dic.Add(_index, List<_item>);

     return dic;

}
```

El caso en cuestión es que tengo una Dicionario que alberga una lista, cuando quiero sacar la lista del diccionario esta se convierte en un objeto y no me deja usar los métodos de List<>. Puedo castear el objeto que me devuelve a partir de su interface (ya en este diccionario tengo varias lista de con la misma interface ).

Puedo castearlo así?

```
List<IItem> martillo = dictionary["Martillo"] as List<IItem>;
```

O tengo que hacerlo a la fuerza así?

```
List<Martillo> martillo = dictionary["Martillo"] as List<Martillo>;
```

Comment: La forma mas sencilla es probarlo, pero en principio si debería funcionarte un cast al interface :)

Comment: Llevo una semana intentando hacer un diccionario único con multiples listas.

Entonces puedo añadir a una clase la variable global de Dictionary<string, List<IItem>> ?

Comment: Yo ya te avisé en otra pregunta que lo que intentas no va a darte mas que dolores de cabeza... :) Pero si todas las listas comparten interface, yo creo que debría funcionar

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar tu código no compila. Le faltan algunas `>` al final de los tipos y en el caso del `Add` supongo que el `item`que le pasas lo quieres envolver en una lista. Haciendo esos cambios deberíoa quedar así

```
public Dictionary<string, List<T>> addDictionary<T>(T _item, string _index)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<T>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<T>>();
    dic.Add(_index, new List<T>(){ _item });
    return dic;
}
```

Ahora si dado ese código podrías hace por ejemplo

```
var dic = addDictionary(martillo, "Martillo");
var listMartillo = dic["Martillo"]; // la variable listMartillo es de tipo List<Martillo> y contiene un elemento.
```

Segundo, si ese diccionario solo va a contener Listas de `Item` te recomiendo que pongas un `constraint` que le indique justamente esto al método: `where T: IItem`

```
public Dictionary<string, List<T>> addDictionary<T>(T _item, string _index) where T : IItem
{
    Dictionary<string, List<T>> dic = new Dictionary<string, List<T>>();
    dic.Add(_index, new List<T>(){ _item });
    return dic;
}
```